# how to specify file path that includes & in .bat file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to copy a file from one location to another using a .bat file

```
copy ""\\PRDHILQW01\LVFPF9\MTHHEDGLIAB.TXT"  "\\PRDHILFT04\L&i-ia&rs\PRODUCTION\RS-Actuarial\MTL\Download\VTG1\mthhedgliab_%yyyy%%mm%%dd%.txt" /y"
```

I get this error

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
'i-ia' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What do I need to do to get the &s in the file path recognized as legit part of the file path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why the extra quotes? The `&` must be either quoted, or escaped as `^&`. Your extra enclosing quotes are making it so that the quoting does not work properly - you have a quoted empty string `""` at the beginning, quoted spaces `"  "` between the file names, and `" \y"` at the end. Everything else is unquoted.

Simply remove the outer quotes and everthing works as you want.

```
copy "\\PRDHILQW01\LVFPF9\MTHHEDGLIAB.TXT"  "\\PRDHILFT04\L&i-ia&rs\PRODUCTION\RS-Actuarial\MTL\Download\VTG1\mthhedgliab_%yyyy%%mm%%dd%.txt" /y
```

Comment: I had tried using ^& - that didn't work either.  I have tried it without outer quotes, but I will try that again.

Comment: @user2217642 - Is the COPY command part of a larger command that you are not showing? If not, then simply removing the outer quotes should work.